# Prove any simple path joining any two vertices in a tree is unique

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, graph-theory

Let $P$ be a simple path joining vertices $A$ and $B$ in a tree $T.$ We will prove $P$ is the only simple path in $T$ from $A$ to $B$ by showing that any simple path $Q$ in $T$ from $A$ to $B$ must contain every edge of $P.$

Suppose $UV$ is an edge of $P$ that is not in $Q.$ The subgraph $T - UV$ still contains a path from $U$ to $V$. If $U$ (as opposed to $V$) is closer to $A,$ then there's a path from $U$ to $A$ (this path is on $P$). There's another another path $Q$ from $A$ to be $B$ and finally a path from $B$ to $V$ which is on $P.$ The union of all these paths from $U$ to $V$ is simple because $P, Q$ are simple. So the removed edge $UV$ and the simple path from $U$ to $V$ form a cycle.

---

Does this proof work?

Comment: Let A-...-X-...-B be a simple path in T. Suppose there is another path A-...-Y-...-B. Then, A-...-X-...-B-...-Y-...-A is a cycle which is a contradiction that T is a tree.

Comment: Rather than say "$U$ is closer to $A$", it might be better to say that $U$ occurs earlier in the $A$ to $B$ path $P$ than  $V$. Technically $V$ could be closer to $A$ in the graph if the path goes really far away from $A$. Interestingly, your proof works well with the definition of a tree as a maximally connected graph.